# Static library with cocoapod dependency: define in Podspec s.dependency, in Podfile, or both?

Tags: ios, static-libraries, cocoapods

I am converting a static library that we use in-house into a CocoaPod, so that our host applications can simply pull it in by referencing it in their Podfiles.  This static library in turn depends upon a third-party Pod called HockeySDK.

In my static library's Podspec, I indicate the HockeySDK dependency as follows:

```
 # MyStaticLib requires the latest HockeySDK framework:
 s.dependency "HockeySDK", "3.6.4"
```

I also indicate the dependency in the Podfile that is in the root directory of my static library:

```
target "MyStaticLib" do
   pod "HockeySDK", "3.6.4"
```

This seems to work fine - if I reference MyStaticLib in the Podfile of MyApp, it pulls in MyStaticLib and also magically pulls in the HockeySDK dependency, and all is good in the world.

What is the difference between these two seemingly redundant mechanisms for indicating the HockeySDK dependency?  Why would I use one or not the other or both?

Answer (score 0):

The first scenario is used to indicate that your library has a run-time (and also compile-time, because in cocoapods essentially all run-time things are also compile-time) dependency on HockeySDK.

The second scenario says your target depends on HockeySDK in order to build.

The difference is pretty subtle but is more obvious if you're not statically linking. Since you're linking statically, a compile-time and run-time dependency is the same thing (meaning the second scenario is the same as the first).

If you were linking dynamically against HockeySDK, then the host application needs to be made aware of this so it can provide the dependent library when linking your library. The way to do that is by propagating the dependency via the podspec.

In the podfile, you declare 1. a target and also 2. that you need the object file as well as the headers from HockeySDK in order to compile the target. This only impacts the building of your own library. People consuming your library use the spec not the Podfile.